# TFS lab build - get staging drop folder

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We have a customized lab build. We are using the latest build from a specific build definition.
Our testing agent is on another network with shared drop folder, and we need to copy files to this folder before running the tests.
The latest folder is defined in the staging section of the build definition (under Build Defaults). How can I get it in the xaml?
I tried "BuildDetail.DropLocation", but gets nothing (prints an empty string).

We are using VS2012, the server is TFS 2013.

Thanks,
Annat.

Update: Found the solution in my case. Just had  to use "BuildDetail.DropLocationRoot".

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some note on the subject on a [post](http://blog.casavian.eu/blog/2014/06/28/why-do-you-copy-all-those-binaries/), which can give you some ideas on managing drop folders and avoiding copies.

Answering your question, the simplest way is to use the [`TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION` environment variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx) in a script.

Comment: Hi. from the link to the env. variablel, it seems that it works only from VS2013. we are using 2012.

Comment: Hi. The server is 2013, We are using VS2012. Anyway, I found a solution. just had to use "BuildDetail.DropLocationRoot". Thanks.